# Trouble activating Jquery gallery

Tags: jquery, unslider

I've worked with alot of jquery galleries before but this one won't work.I'm using Twitter bootstrap and I wonder if it's JS bootstrap files are interfering with the JS file for the Unslider jquery gallery -> Unslider that I'm using.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/half-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-static-top " role="navigation"style="background-image:url('img/ap.jpg');">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Galleries</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

   <!--  -->

   <div id="banner">
   <ul>
        <li> <img src="img2.jpg"/> </li>
       <li>  <img src="img3.jpg"/> </li>
        <li> <img src="img11.jpg"/> </li>
        <li> <img src="img7.jpg"/> </li>
        <li> <img src="img9.jpg"/> </li>
    </ul>

    </div>


</div> -->
 <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Copyright 2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Other JS files -->
    <script src="js/unslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 500,               
    delay: 3000,              
    complete: function() {},  
    keys: true,               
    dots: true,              
    fluid: false              
});
});
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get so lazy sometimes and dont read code right   , Found my mistake.It's `class ="banner"` and not `id="banner"`.Sorry